# How to pass label data to another label in the second view controller

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, pushviewcontroller

I've been searching for passing label data to another view controller, and found the following solution. However, it doesn't show the label text in another view controller.

please help

SecondViewController Header

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *copy;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *data;
```

In SecondViewController Implementation

```
copy.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth| UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
copy.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
copy.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your data: %@", _data]; // Make use of the exposed data property
[self.view addSubview:copy];
```

In FirstViewController Implementation

```
- (void)passDataForward
{
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    secondViewController.data = _label.text; // Set the exposed property
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: you have not specified any frame for the label. Where is that label setup code in SecondViewController, make sure it is actually after the data has been set.

Comment: did u check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Save the strings content in the first implementation file and load it in the second**

Save your label.text in first class:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:Label.text forKey:@"Your key"];
```

Load it in the second class:

```
Label.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Your key"];
```

**2. Use parameters**

In the first class you have to implement the second
`#import "SecondClassName.h"`
In second class create a function with parameters.

```
- (void)setLabelText:(NSString *)LabelText
{
    Label.text = LabelText
}
```

And in the first class you pass the data by adding these two lines:

```
SecondViewControllerName *Second = [[SecondViewControllerName alloc] init];
[Second setLabelText:label.text];
```

Comment: i just tried method 2, [Second setLabelText:label.text]; returns an error "NO visible @interface for 'SecondViewController' declares the selector 'setLabelText:'

Comment: You have to implement your second class to your first, so in your first class say: #import "SecondViewController.h".

Comment: And if that doesn't work, you can always use method 1. That might be easier too. Just save the label text in class 1, and load it in class 2. That will always work.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to pass `NSString` then `NSUserDefaults`. Just to pass data it will be better if you use `NSString`

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
secondViewController.Stringdata = _label.text; // Set the exposed property
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

> In SecondViewController

```
@interface SecondViewController :UIViewController
{

}    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;
```

> In the place to set text in label you can use

```
Label.text = Stringdata
```